# Running Qt Creator on CentOS release 5.8 - Cannot resolve 'dbus_get_version' in your libdbus-1

Tags: qt, qt-creator

I succesfully build Qt 4.8 (without QtWebKit) on CentOS 5.8 (Qt Assistant and the demo's run fine). I also built Qt Creator 2.4.1 against Qt 4.8. I did not observe any errors during the process of building Qt Creator. However, when I attempt to run Qt Creator I receive the following error:

[root@localhost bin]# ./qtcreator
Cannot resolve 'dbus_get_version' in your libdbus-1.
Aborted

Has anybody encountered this error before? How did you fix it? Unfortunately upgrading to a better OS (such as Ubuntu) is not an option for me.

Thanks,

David

Answer (score 0):

QtDBus module loads libdbus-1 library in runtime (via dlopen). That's why you don't have compile/link errors.
You can try either to upgrade dbus package (or whatever package contains libdbus-1.so) or use previous version of Qt.

(In Gentoo QtDBus-4.8 depends on dbus-1.2 and QtDBus-4.7.4 depends on dbus-1.0.2).